# How to expand value of 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let say I have 3d array (`3x3x1`) like this:

```py
[[[149]
  [121]
  [189]]

 [[ 32]
  [225]
  [ 44]]

 [[ 33]
  [133]
  [ 11]]]
```

How can I expand all values so they can be the same in the deepest one (`3x3x3`) like this:

```py
[[[149 149 149]
  [121 121 121]
  [189 189 189]]

 [[ 32  32  32]
  [225 225 225]
  [ 44  44  44]]

 [[ 33  33  33]
  [133 133 133]
  [ 11  11  11]]]
```

I have tried this:

```py
for i in range(len(array)):
  for j in range(len(array[i])):
    array[i][j] = np.array(list(array[i][j]) * 3)
print(array)
```

But it gives me an error:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (1,)
```

For generalization purposes, how do I achieve this with `m x n x p` shape format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various options. For instance: [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html), [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [[149], [121], [189]],
    [[ 32], [225], [ 44]],
    [[ 33], [133], [ 11]]
])

out = np.repeat(arr, 3, axis=2)
# or
out = np.broadcast_to(arr, (3, 3, 3))
# or
out = np.tile(arr, (1, 1, 3))
```

choose whichever works most cleanly for you.

Also note that your array with shape `(3, 3, 1)` might function as an array with shape `(3, 3, 3)` automagically without manually repeating due to [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is also np.c_[] way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [[149], [121], [189]],
    [[ 32], [225], [ 44]],
    [[ 33], [133], [ 11]]
])

print(np.c_[arr, arr, arr])
```